# Return inherited values from join on junction table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inheritance, join, common-table-expression

For the sake of simplicity, suppose I have the following tables:

```
role

id  name        inherits
----------------------------------
1   Base        null
2   Role2       1
3   Role3       1
4   Role3Child  3

item

id  name            org_id      
----------------------------------
1   item1            4210
2   item2            4210
3   item3            4210
4   item4            4210
5   item5            4210
6   item6            4210


role_item_junction

id  role_id     item_id      item_value
----------------------------------
1   1       1            true
2   1       2            false
3   2       3            D
4   3       3            F
5   4       4            12
```

role_id 4 here has inherited all the items by inheriting from role_id 3 which inherits from role_id 1.

When I query for all items that pertain to role_id 4, I want to return:

1. all items assigned to role_id 4 and the item_value
2. all items that role_id 4 inherits from and their item_values
3. all other items in a certain org_id

How can I write a query that returns all items that role_id 4 should have access to?  I want the output to look similar to the following when I query for role_id 4:

```
id(item.id) org_id      name(item.name)     item_value
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       4210        item1           true
2       4210        item2           false
3       4210        item3           F
4       4210        item4           12
5       4210        item5           NULL <--not in the junction table
6       4210        item6           NULL <--not in the junction table
```

Don't know how to return the inherited item values in the junction table from my left join:

```
@orgid varchar(5) = '4210',
@roleid int = 4


SELECT item.*, ri.item_value AS selected_item_value
--SNIP LOTS OF OTHER COLUMNS RETURNED

FROM item
LEFT JOIN role_item AS ri ON item.id = ri.item_id 
AND ri.role_id = @roleid
???? how do I return the ri.item_value of items that roleid 4 inherits from?
--SNIP LOTS OF OTHER IRRELEVANT JOINS

WHERE 
((@orgid IS NULL or @orgid = '') or item.org_id = @orgid) AND
item.date_archived IS NULL 
AND ri.date_archived IS NULL
```

Comment: By the way, I tried creating a CTE and setting the level of inheritance of each role, then declaring a counter and looping until I hit that level but it seemed like there had to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of an easy way to solve it without a recursive CTE, but this should work:

```
;WITH roleCascaded AS
(SELECT id, id as inherits
FROM role
UNION ALL
SELECT r2.id, r1.inherits
FROM role r1 
INNER JOIN roleCascaded r2 on r1.id = r2.inherits AND r1.inherits IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT item.*, ri.item_value AS selected_item_value
FROM item
LEFT OUTER JOIN role_item AS ri ON item.id = ri.item_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN roleCascaded AS rc ON rc.inherits = ri.role_id AND rc.id = @roleid
WHERE 
((@orgid IS NULL or @orgid = '') or item.org_id = @orgid) AND
item.date_archived IS NULL 
AND ri.date_archived IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  This is identical to what I came up with prior to you answering.  However, the role inheritance idea added unneeded complexity to an otherwise extremely simple application so I phased it out.